# Using Powershell to get AWS EC2 Console field "Platform Details"

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, amazon-ec2

I am looking to catalog our AWS EC2's, I have the Powershell script written, but I want to pull the information from the AWS Console EC2 Page under `Instance` called `Platorm Details`
This will show if the EC2 had SQL Server when created. Meaning we don't need to have a license for it, since we are leasing it from AWS.
I can not find anywhere to get this field via AWS Powershell Modules

The field is highlighted in this screen capture of the Console page.

[image]